# Reverted Transaction For Any Adress (require not functioning as intended) in Solidity

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, solidity-0.8.x, solidity-0.6.x

I'm in the process of making a decentralized polling web app (relatively new to smart contract development). The idea is that a user connects their wallet via MetaMask, creates a poll or votes on a poll. So far I have the functionality for how the creating a poll but I'm running into a problem with the voting function.

**Project Structure**

Two solidity files exist: a **Voting** contract and a contract factory called **VotingFactory**.

The Voting contract handles the vote function and make sure that an address hasn't voted more than once. Essentially, each voting contract represents one poll. A mapping is created in Voting and after a user votes a their address maps to a bool to check if they have voted or not

```
mapping (address=>bool) hasVoted;
```

The VotingFactory handles the creation of a new Voting contract/poll and pushes the contract to an array. There is also an array of structs that represents data to each relevant contract which is used to push to the front end.

On the front end, I have a react app using ethers.js to interface with the smart contract(s).

**Problem**

I am able to successfully submit a poll and vote. As expected, when I vote with the same account on MetaMask the transaction is reverted with a reason string. Due to this:

```
require(!hasVoted[msg.sender],"You already have voted on this poll!");
```

When I change account, I would expect to be able to vote once more with this new account, however the transaction is still reverted and I am told I already have voted! I can't seem to figure out why this happening and assume it is some sort of logical problem in the way I have structured my contract(s).

Can anyone take a look at the contracts and aid my sanity by pointing out what I am doing wrong?

**Voting.sol:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >= 0.7.0 < 0.9.0;
pragma abicoder v2;

contract Voting {

    string contractName = "Voting";

    address creator;
    bytes32 name;

    bytes32[] options;
    uint256[] voteCount;
    uint256 pollId;

    mapping (address=>bool) hasVoted;

    constructor (
                address sender,
                bytes32 _name,
                bytes32[] memory _options,
                uint256[] memory _voteCount,
                uint256 _pollId          
    ){
        creator = sender;
        name = _name;
        options = _options;
        voteCount = _voteCount;
        pollId = _pollId;
    }

    function vote(uint optionID) external{
        require(!hasVoted[msg.sender],"You already have voted on this poll!");
        voteCount[optionID]++;
        hasVoted[msg.sender] = true;
    }

    function getVoteCount() public view returns(uint256[] memory) {
        return voteCount;
    }
}
```

**VotingFactory.sol:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >= 0.7.0 < 0.9.0;
pragma abicoder v2;
import "./Voting.sol";

contract VotingFactory {
    string contractName = "VotingFactory";

    struct PollInfo {
        address pollCreator;
        bytes32 pollName;
        bytes32[] pollOptions;
        uint256[] pollVoteCount;
        uint256 pollInfoID;
    }

    address sender = msg.sender;
    Voting[] public polls;
    PollInfo[] public pollInfoList;


    function createVotingContract(bytes32 _name, bytes32[] memory _options) public {
        
        uint256 pollIndex = polls.length;
        uint256[] memory _voteCount = new uint256[](_options.length);

        Voting voting = new Voting(sender,_name,_options, _voteCount, pollIndex);
        polls.push(voting);

        pollInfoList.push(PollInfo({pollCreator:sender,
                                    pollName:_name,
                                    pollOptions:_options,
                                    pollVoteCount:_voteCount,
                                    pollInfoID: pollIndex
        }));

    }
    function vote(uint256 _pollId, uint256 _optionId) public {
        polls[_pollId].vote(_optionId);
        pollInfoList[_pollId].pollVoteCount = polls[_pollId].getVoteCount();
    }

    function getPollInfoList() public view returns(PollInfo[] memory) {
        return pollInfoList;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to connect Metamask also with the other accounts. Click the the green dot where it's written "connected" and connect everything. Otherwise Metamask will use the first account even if you switched

Comment: @0xSanson I figured that after awhile. My connect wallet button was showing that I had changed account. When I checked the logs in my hardhat testnet however, it seems that the account wasn't actually changing in ethers.js. Still trying to figure this out unfortunately.